# How to get Firebase Data using Spinner Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I Need to get Firebase Realtime Database Data Using Spinner.

Like Spinner - **Product Name**

After selecting Product Name need to fetch data automatically **Rate** and **Stock Quantity**

[image: Database Screenshot]

[image: Stock Row Screenshot]

```
public class ChrompetSalesFillAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChrompetSalesFillAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Model> fill_list;

    public ChrompetSalesFillAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> fill_list){
        this.context = context;
        this.fill_list = fill_list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChrompetSalesFillAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sales_report_row, parent, false);
        return new ChrompetSalesFillAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChrompetSalesFillAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Model model = fill_list.get(position);
        
        holder._stock_qty.setText(model.getProduct_stock_qty());
        holder._product_rate.setText(model.getProduct_rate());
        holder._product_id.setText(model.getProduct_id());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fill_list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView  _product_rate, _stock_qty,_product_name,_product_id;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            _product_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name_sales_fill);
            _product_id =itemView.findViewById(R.id.pro_id_sales_fill);
            _product_rate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate_chr_sales_fill);
            _stock_qty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_chr_sales_fill);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far in code?

Comment: Sir..I dont have any Idea how to get Spinner from Firebase.. Please Help

Comment: and also I need to get  STOCK and RATE from same PRODUCT. which I select

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: this code is not showing error but i need to develop PRODUCT ID as a spinner.. After that when i select Product Id need to get STOCK Quantity and RATE... and then I enter PCS...it will Store as SALES..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it possible with do like this

1. Retrieve all product name or you can change it to other data, [You can follow this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-retrieve-data-from-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-android/#:%7E:text=After%20creating%20a%20new%20project,Navigate%20to%20Firebase%20Realtime%20Database.)

   ```
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDataRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("stock");
    Arraylist list;
    TextView textview1;
    TextView textview2;
    Spinner spinner;

    textview1 = findViewById(YourId1);
    textview2 = findViewById(YourId2);
    spinner = findViewById(YourId3);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Store it to arraylist, you can do it with looping

   ```
    mDataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name  = String.valueOf(ds.child(snapshot.getKey()).child("name"));
                list.add(name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
   ```
3. Create spinner dan make arraylist as spinner value, [You can follow this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spinner-in-android-using-java-with-example/)

   ```
   spinner = findViewById(/*Your Id Here*/);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DetailTransactionActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
4. Select value of spinner and make new variable which have value of selected spinner value

   ```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    String selectedValue = list.get(position);
                    compare(selectedValue);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
   ```
5. Make loop and if statement inside it for comparison all product name equal with variable which you already create in last step. Create this in other function and call it inside onItemSelected

   ```
    public void compare(String selectedValue){
     mDataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                /*Next Step*/
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
   ```

}

6. If equals, retrieve data you needed and set it to textview or edittext

   ```
   for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(ds.child(snapshot.getKey()).child("name").equals(selectedValue)){
        String rate = String.valueOf(ds.child(snapshot.getKey()).child("product_rate"));
        String quantity = String.valueOf(ds.child(snapshot.getKey()).child("product_stock_qty"));
        textview1.setText(rate);
        textview2.setText(quantity);
        break;
                }
            }
   ```

Comment: Hello Sir, I don't understand , could you please sent me a code better for my understand.. Thank You

Comment: I add some code, check it now